# making background thread to check if network available and notify when ever it is available

Tags: android

I made a service and a Activity, I need the processing in the following Manner

Like the service starts automatically at application boots up, and check periodically if there is network available or not, and whenever it is available then notify to the user.

How i can do this, i want some alarm manager or blinking screen until the network is available

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make an `BroadcastReceiver` that will be triggered when the connectivity status has changed, by adding this in your `manifest`:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action
                android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and then in your `receiver` you can check if you have connectivity:

```
   public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()!=null&&cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()){
           //Send a broadcast to your service or activity that you have network
           //...
       }else{
           LOG.i("Network UNAVAILABLE");
       }
   }

}
```